# How to dump jquery before bootstrap in product environment using assetic in symfony?

Tags: symfony, assetic

I have a block in my twig template

```
{% javascripts 
'../app/Resources/public/js/jquery.min.js'
'../app/Resources/public/js/*' filter="" output="bundles/app/js/app.js" %}
<script  src="{{ asset_url}}" ></script>{% endjavascripts %}
```

I want Assetic to dump two files: `jquery` and `bootstrap` but `bootstrap` is loaded before `jquery`, I'm using `prod` environment to dump two files, how can I dump `jquery` before `bootstrap` in `prod` environment?

Comment: Where is your bootstrap.js file located?

Comment: Hi Michael ,my Bootstrap.js file located at app/Resources/public/js/bootstrap.min.js

Comment: Why do you think that your `jquery` is loaded after `bootstrap`? Now your code tells me that it first load `jquery`, then `bootstrap`, then `jquery` again. It loads `jquery` twice but first one is before `bootstrap` loading.

Answer (score 0):

Now you have code that loads `jquery` twice: first time before `bootstrap`, second: after.

To have control over order of loading scripts you have to define all paths to scripts explicitly in your `javascripts` block:

```
{% javascripts 
    '../app/Resources/public/js/jquery.min.js'
    '../app/Resources/public/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    '../app/Resources/public/js/some_other_script.js'
    '../app/Resources/public/js/and_so_on.js'
    filter="" output="bundles/app/js/app.js"
%}
<script  src="{{ asset_url}}" ></script>{% endjavascripts %}
```

Also I would recommend you not to load `jquery` and `bootstrap` from your own server. You can use Google CDN for that purpose. It has one big advantage: many users all over the world can have these files cached in their browsers because of other websites are also use CDN.

Comment: Hi Michael, I'm trying it, it dump one file that url like 'bundles/app/js/app.js',but internal file bootstrap loaded after jquery.

Comment: You need `bootstrap` to be loaded after `jquery` or before?

Comment: I need jquery loaded before bootstrap, how can i do it ?

Comment: But you said that `bootstrap` is already loaded after `jquery`. It means that `jquery` is loaded before `bootstrap`. And now you said that you need it. I'm confused.

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry, it's my bad, i mean i need  i need jquery loaded before bootstrap.And now bootstrap already loaded before jquery, how can i fix it?